# Runtime flexibility of OSGi

Tags: runtime, osgi

To get started with OSGi, thought of asking this since this become unclear to me.
If you have runtime code change as a requirement, OSGi is probably the only possible way to achieve this using Java.
from https://mondula.com/2016/01/11/osgi-benefits-and-drawbacks/

How the runtime flexibility is maintained in OSGi technically?

Answer (score 1):

This is a large question that would be impractical to fully answer here. The following is a simplified overview.

OSGi allocates a Java `ClassLoader` for each resolved bundle. When a bundle is updated, OSGi first sends a stop signal to the bundle, allowing it to release resources and prepare to be garbage collected.

The new bundle is then re-resolved against its requirements, which may have changed compared to the previous version. Assuming the new version still resolves (i.e. its requirements are still satisfied) then OSGi allocates a new `ClassLoader`, uses that to load the classes in the bundle, and if the bundle has an activator and was in `ACTIVE` state before the update, sends a start signal to the newly loaded activator.